# OS X webkit bad font rendering

Tags: macos, fonts, webkit, rendering

*Webkit* browsers **Chrome** and **Safari**, same page font renders different from Firefox. 
Is there any trick to make fonts look like Firefox ?

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Fix: -webkit-text-stroke: 0.35px